# Opening a file that's already in use

Tags: c#, .net, file, filestream, ioexception

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = File.Open(GetCurrentWallpaper(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
```

I'm writing an app that needs to open the current wallpaper like this every time it's changed.
I first access the registry to get the wallpaper's path (GetCurrentWallpaper), and use a FileSystemWatcher to do stuff with the wallpaper when it's changed.
Oddly, it only works once. If the wallpaper is accessed a second time(it doesn't matter how long I wait), my app crashed with an IOException telling me that I can't access the file because it's already in use.
If I restart the app, it can access the file again, but, as mentioned above, only once. Else it crashes.
Is there anything I can do in order to gain access to that file?

Edit: More code:

```
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = File.Open(GetCurrentWallpaper(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
                using (Bitmap orig = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(fs, true, false)) {
                    int width = Convert.ToInt32(orig.Width / 3);
                    int height = Convert.ToInt32(orig.Height / 3);

                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
                    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height)) {
                        using (Graphics bmpg = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
                            col = ColorHelper.CalculateAverageColor(bmp, true, 20);
                            fs.Flush();
                            fs.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

//this is in the ColorHelper class
public static System.Drawing.Color CalculateAverageColor(Bitmap bm, bool dropPixels, int colorDiff) {
        int width = bm.Width;
        int height = bm.Height;
        int red = 0;
        int green = 0;
        int blue = 0;
        int minDiversion = colorDiff;
        int dropped = 0;
        long[] totals = new long[] { 0, 0, 0 };
        int bppModifier = bm.PixelFormat == System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb ? 3 : 4;

        BitmapData srcData = bm.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bm.PixelFormat);
        int stride = srcData.Stride;
        IntPtr Scan0 = srcData.Scan0;

        unsafe {
            byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    int idx = (y * stride) + x * bppModifier;
                    red = p[idx + 2];
                    green = p[idx + 1];
                    blue = p[idx];

                    if (dropPixels) {
                        if (Math.Abs(red - green) > minDiversion || Math.Abs(red - blue) > minDiversion || Math.Abs(green - blue) > minDiversion) {
                            totals[2] += red;
                            totals[1] += green;
                            totals[0] += blue;
                        } else {
                            dropped++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        totals[2] += red;
                        totals[1] += green;
                        totals[0] += blue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int count = width * height - dropped;
        int avgR;
        int avgG;
        int avgB;

        if (count > 0) {
            avgR = (int)(totals[2] / count);
            avgG = (int)(totals[1] / count);
            avgB = (int)(totals[0] / count);
        } else {
            avgR = (int)(totals[2]);
            avgG = (int)(totals[1]);
            avgB = (int)(totals[0]);
        }

        bm.UnlockBits(srcData);
        return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(avgR, avgG, avgB);
    }
```

Comment: Does the wallpaper change before the end of your using block?

Comment: Did you try to explicitly call Close and/or Flush before leaving the using block?

Comment: Please post more of your code, I'm pretty sure you're opening it somewhere else and forgetting to close it. Since you're using it in a `using` block, you do not have to explicitly `.Close()` it, that's taken care of, so I'm pretty sure there's something else going on.

Comment: I'm already calling Flush /and/ Close before leaving the using block. And the wallpaper does not change before the end of the block. The operations inside take about 60ms to complete, and no living person on earth is able to non-programmatically change it that fast. :D

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Added more code. Hopefully that makes finding errors easier.

Comment: Just one flaw I see, UnlockBits() must be in a finally block so the code is exception safe.  I don't think the problem is in this code.

Comment: The CalculateAverageColor method is not the problem, it works reliably and that's good enough for me. According to the stacktrace the IOException is thrown on the line where I open the file in the using() block.

Comment: I noticed that that IOException is not thrown anymore when I do Thread.Sleep(1000); before opening the file. So there is indeed /something/ that's still using the file. Is there some way to (reliably) stall my program (for a maximum of ~150ms) until the file is available for use?

Answer (score 0):

If you use fs.Close() than you will release the file for further read operations.